# Way to shorten / refactor multiple plugin values

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, refactoring, javascript-objects

I have some 15-20 highcharts on a single page (using a slider, 1-2 charts per slide), some bar charts, some column charts, some pie charts, with different display options. What I was using was having multiple methods inside my closure where I had methods like `self.drawColumnChart(xPlotColor, yPlotColor, xPlotLabelSize, yPlotLabelSize, ...10 more arguments)`. Inside the same object I have methods like 'drawRevenueChart(), drawLossChart()' etc. `drawRevenueChart()` was calling `self.drawColumnChart(` with 15 arguments. As the number of charts grew, I ended up passing more and more arguments to `self.drawColumnChart(` so I thought I could refactor this by changing the `drawRevenueChart()` as

```
("$id").highcharts(
    {chart: {
        plotOptions: {
            labelSize: '2em'
        },
        xAxis:{
          labelSize: '1.3em',
          formatter: function(){
               return '% ' + this.value;
          }
          ...and so on
        }
    })'
```

I don't need the `self.drawColumnChart(xPlotColor, yPlotColor, xPlotLabelSize, yPlotLabelSize, ...10 more arguments)` any more but I just passed that complexity to `drawRevenueChart()`. `drawRevenueChart()` used to be 2 lines long, but now it's 25 lines long. Same with `drawLossChart()`, it used to be 3 lines long, just calling `self.drawColumnChart(`, but it turned into a 15 line long method after refactor.

Can you guys think of any other way how I can refactor/shorten this? Maybe `drawRevenueChart()` calls `self.drawChart("column", [plotOptions.labelSize: '2em', xAxis: {labelSize: '1.e em'}...`

It just seems that I have to keep repeating

```
plotOptions: {
    labelSize: '2em'
    },
    xAxis:{
        labelSize: '1.3em',
```

all over my closure for each chart with different options. Is there a way to shorten this? I'm already using jQuery `extend()` to extend default chart options with custom options. It's all inside a closure. But regardless of how I refactor this, I find myself repeating the same lines with different options. Any ideas are welcome.

**Update:**

As requested by TrueBlueAussie:

**it used to be:**

```
myClosure{

    var self = this;

    self.drawColumnChart = function(selector, xPlotColour, yPlotColour, xAxisName, yAxisName, xPlotOptionsSize....10 more arguments)
    {
          $(selector).highcharts({
              chart: {
                  type: 'column'
              },
              xPlot:{
                  style:{
                     color: xPlotColour
                  }
              },
              yPlot: {
                  labels: {
                      style:{
                          color: yPlotColour
                      }
                  }
              },
              xAxis:{
                  labels: { 
                     name: xAxisName,
                  }
              }    
          })
    }

    drawRevenueChart: function(data){
        self.drawColumnChart("#chartid1", 'blue', 'red', 'profit', 'month', '1.2em', null, false, null....);
    }

    drawLossChart: function(data){
        self.drawColumnChart("#chartid2", 'orange', 'yellow, 'loss', 'month', '2em' ...);
    }
}
```

**After refactor**

```
drawRevenueChart: function(data){
        $("#chartid1").highcharts({
              chart: {
                  type: 'column'
              },
            xPlot:{
                  style:{
                     color: 'blue'
                  }
              },
              yPlot: {
                  labels: {
                      style:{
                          color: 'red'
                      }
                  }
              },
              xAxis:{
                  labels: { 
                     name: 'profit',
                  }
              }    
        });
    }

drawLossChart: function(data){
    $("chartid2").highcharts({
        xplot:{
            style:{
               color: 'orange'
            }
        },
        xAxis:{
           labels:{
               name: 'loss',
               color: 'puke'
           }
        }
    }
};
```

So I just moved the 3 level deep object setting from one method to another, no real gain.

Comment: For something like this (refactoring required) you need to show full code, preferably with a working demo.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie I thought I gave enough info on here mate, the object I use is some 500 lines, with ajax calls to get chart data and all that, so not sure how to show full code with a working demo. If you can tell me where it's unclear what I'm doing then I'll update the question.

Comment: Well in Highcharts you can set global/default options for all charts per one page, just like in demos, which are called themes: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-basic/dark-unica

Comment: Referencing multiple functions by name, out of context, is not a good way for coders (i.e. *us*) to read code. How about at least the functions with the function body remove/trimmed?

Comment: @PawełFus Thanks for the link but I think I have that covered. I have the common options stored already but some charts need blue line, others need red line. Some charts need xlabel to be bold, some italic. Some charts need `3px` for `xAxis plot lines width`, some need it `1px`, etc. I end up writing all these options into an object for every chart.

Comment: You can prepare global "pattern" per charts and then use Highcharts.merge() function to combine "pattern" with custom option per particular chart.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie It took me a while to add the update mate, I hope the update will show you what I mean. I'm looking for a way to shorten all this. Either way I keep repeating setting the same option values. Is there way to shorten this so I can avoid writing `chart:{xlabel:{style:{colour:''` for each method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, that is clearer now. This is not really a code refactoring problem, so much as a data-refactoring problem. The only solution I can suggest is to find common data in the structures, store those branches as vars within your scope and `$.extend()` them together to build the final options structure.

e.g.

```
myClosure {
    // Put any common settings in shared vars
    var columnChart = {
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        }
        // any other common properties for a column chart
    };

    var barChart = {
        chart: {
            type: 'barchart'
        }
        // any other common properties for a bar chart
    }

    var self = this;

    self.drawColumnChart = function (selector, data) {
        $(selector).highcharts($.extend({}, columnChart, data));
    }

    drawRevenueChart: function (data) {
        self.drawColumnChart("#chartid1", {
            xPlot: {
                style: {
                    color: 'blue'
                }
            },
            yPlot: {
                labels: {
                    style: {
                        color: 'red'
                    }
                }
            },
            xAxis: {
                labels: {
                    name: 'month name',
                }
            }
        });
    }

    drawLossChart: function (data) {
        self.drawColumnChart("#chartid2", {
            xPlot: {
                style: {
                    color: 'orange'
                }
            },
            yPlot: {
                labels: {
                    style: {
                        color: 'yellow'
                    }
                }
            },
            xAxis: {
                labels: {
                    name: 'loss',
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

This has the advantage that each call is still readable, if you know the HighCharts option structure, and is therefore easier to maintain.

Unless you use a strongly typed JS language (like TypeScript), using functions with loads of parameters is *human*-error-prone so best avoided.

Comment: I'm already using `var chartOptions = {default:{...}, bar:{chart:{type:'bar'},pie..}}` and `($.extend({}, chartOptions.bar, data)`. But there's still heaps of multi-level nested `{ settings1: {a: '2', b: '3'}, settings2: { setting3: {...` lines in the code, in the settings variable and 15 other `self.function`s, taking up too many lines. When I'm reading the closure code, I miss the real function code, as most of the code is settings. But like you said if I didn't write the settings,I ended up with a method which takes s** loads of parameters.Maybe I will put all the settings in a separate JS.

Comment: See the solution I came up with mate, if you're interested. PS: Can you type bit slower today when answering questions? Or go watch tv or something, they have bonanza re-runs :)

Comment: @artm: Stop assuming I still live in Australia... Been in the UK for 17 years (telly is a bit different here). P.S. that is the same solution, just in a different layout. The principal is the same :P

Comment: Assumptions are the source of all f**, how's that go? You seemed to be online when I am after work so I assumed since we're online at the same time, he/she must be living here too. PS: I don't think the principal is the same :)

Comment: @artm: They both are simply merging separate common properties == "Same principal". The implementation differences are purely down to different function decomposition. Not dissing your code BTW, just saying.

Answer (score 1):

What I ended up doing is I created an object inside the plugin which handles all the highcharts options with a single `drawChart` function which takes an object. i.e.

```
var plugin = function(){

    helper.drawChart({
        legendEnabled: true,
        selector: '#divID',
        backgroundColor: '#FF0000', //etc all other options
    });

    var chartHelper = function(){
         var defaults = {
            _common:{
               //common highcharts options
               {
                   legend: false //etc
               }
            },
            _bar:{
               chart: 'bar', //all common bar options
            },
            get bar(){ return $.extend({}, _common, _bar); }
         }

         this.drawChart = function(options){
            var default = {};
            if (options.legendEnabled){
                default.legend = true;
            }

            if (options.yLabelText){
                default.yTitle = { text = options.yLabelText }
            }//and other options here

            $(options.selector).highchart($.extend({}, defaults.bar, default);
         }
    }

    var helper = new chartHelper();
}
```

I have some 20 charts inside the plugin and this saved me some 600 lines. All the chart logic is inside the helper, it doesn't clutter the plugin code, I don't need to keep repeating `.highcharts({ 20 different options  })` inside each draw function, it's just once I need to do that now.